# Python & Stats: fitting to mixed distribution?

Tags: python, scipy

Sometimes, the data is not from a single distribution, but from several distributions.

For example, `y = 0.4*X + 0.6*Y`, `y` has 40% chance of coming from distribution `X`, and 60% chance of coming from distribution `Y`. A intro could be find here: http://www.r-bloggers.com/a-brief-introduction-to-mixture-distributions/.

The problem is, given the dataset, is there any good way to fit them in `python`?

I find a tutorial about `R`: http://www.r-bloggers.com/fitting-mixture-distributions-with-the-r-package-mixtools/, but didn't find anything about `python`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your distributions are Gaussian, then [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/) has some good methods to fit to mixed distributions, so called Gaussian mixing models.
There is a good explanation [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/mixture.html).
They also use expectation maximization, just like the R package mentioned in your link.

Comment: This is very informative, never realize there is such a thing in scikit-learn, thanks alot!

Comment: I've looked the method, there sever problems that I got, could u help me with that?: 1. How can I get the fitted distributions' parameters?(mean, std for normal etc. and relative frequency) 2. How can I get the combined distribution? .  I find the example, but it's really complex:http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/mixture/plot_gmm_classifier.html#example-mixture-plot-gmm-classifier-py

Comment: I agree with @cqcn1991, I also was looking for a Python equivalent, I read the example (which is supposed to do model selection and clustering, but not a regular regression and regression results, I think! Any help?